# Open function definition in Vim split window?

Tags: vim

I know you can use `ctrl-]` in Vim to jump to a definition, but is there a way to have it open in a split window rather than the current buffer? I know I could just open a new split window and then use `ctrl-]`, but is there a faster way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<C-w><C-]>
```

is unfortunately documented far away from `<C-]>` but it does what you want.

See `:help window-tag`.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.