# Vim: how to jump to definition in a split window

Tags: vim, neovim

I would like to define a command, `gv`, which jumps to definition in a split window. I'm aware that `gd` is the command to jump to definition but in the existing window.

I tried this mapping:

```
nnoremap <silent> gv :vsplit<CR>gd
```

But it didn't work. It opened up the exactly same file in a split window, without actually jumping to definition. Seems like the `gd` command after `<CR>` was ignored. How do I fix this?

I saw some [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52413586/9666932) mentioning `<C-]>` but is there away to implement this without generating tags?

Hopefully this makes sense. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:help gd` jumps to the local definition of the word under the cursor. That "local definition" is always in the same buffer *no matter what* so I hope you don't expect it to jump to some other buffer.

Your mapping:

```
nnoremap <silent> gv :vsplit<CR>gd
```

works as expected, here: the window is split and the cursor jumps to the local definition of the word under the cursor:

[image: gd]

First jump is with `gd`, second jump is with your `gv`.

---

If you want a "jump to definition" that works across files, `gd` and `gD` are **not** what you want. See `:help ctags`, `:help cscope` and `:help include-search`. Note that those features are not particularly smart. If you want something that understands your code better than you do, look elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to define a new mapping/command for this. If you press `CTRL-W d` (or type `:dsp <word>`), it will show you the definition in a new window. From the documentation:

```
CTRL-W CTRL-D                   *CTRL-W_CTRL-D* *CTRL-W_d*
CTRL-W d        Open a new window, with the cursor on the first
            macro definition line that contains the keyword
            under the cursor.  The search starts from the
            beginning of the file.  If a count is given, the
            count'th matching line is jumped to.
```

However, if you really want to press `gv` and have the definition shown, an alternative to romainl's solution is the following:

```
nnoremap gv :vertical dsplit <C-R><C-w><cr>
```